# How to Find Lowest Value Higher than 0 and Also Return The Matrix Row Index?

Tags: r

I want to find the lowest value excluding 0, and here is my code:

```
A = 600000000
B = 450000000
C = 300000000
D = 150000000
E = 90000000
F = 60000000
G = 30000000
H = 15000000
rpl.list <- matrix(c(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H),ncol=1)
apply(rpl.list, 2, FUN = function(x) {min(x[x > 0])})
```

the result is:

```
[1] 1.5e+07
```

and the value is in rpl.list[8], I want to get the "8" value which is the row number of that value. How to get it?
I know I can loop the rpl.list to find the exact same value with the result and return the i, like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(rpl.list)){
    if(rpl.list[i] == apply(rpl.list, 2, FUN = function(x) {min(x[x > 0])})){
        temp = i
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a simple way to return the row number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all values less than or equal to zero, and then sort the remaining values. Find which value in your data matches the smallest value, and give its index.

```
which(rpl.list==sort(rpl.list[rpl.list>0])[1])
```

Comment: this one works with the dataset that has the minimum value on multiple rows

Answer (score 4):

We can use `which.min` after replacing the values less than or equal to 0 to `NA`

```
which.min(replace(rpl.list, rpl.list <= 0, NA))
```